# When looped, memory address not being displayed sequentially while skipping intermediate memory

Tags: microcontroller, memory, c++, addressing

I am trying to run through a sequence of memory and display it on the command window. Here is the code:

```
int addr[10];              //Address addr is 32 bit
for{int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++}
{
  int *p = &addr[i];        //Pointing to the 32 bit addresses from 0 to 9
  cout<<p<<endl;            //Display the pointed addresses
}
return 0;
 }
```

Output:

```
 002AF948             //address of addr[0]
 002AF94C            //address of addr[1]
 002AF950            //address of addr[2]
 ....upto i = 9
```

Question: In the output, Isn't the address of *addr[1]* supposed to be 002AF949 instead of 002AF94C?. Why is it skipping the memory addresses 002AF49, 002AF4A, 002AF4B and then displaying addr[1] address as 002AF94C?. The same thing happens with addr[2] also.

Why is the pointer skipping these intermediate 32 bit addresses when incremented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `i` is declared as `int` it will take 4 bytes to store each value of `i`. Since each address corresponds to a single byte, it will take 4 locations to store an `int`.

In your case,

It will take memory range `002AF948 - 002AF94B` to store 0 (`0x00000000`)

It will take memory range `002AF94C - 002AF94F` to store 1 (`0x00000001`)

And so on...

Comment: but each address such as 002AF948 is 32 bit right?. So a transition from 002AF948 to 002AF94B is 128 bits!

Comment: Why will it take a memory range of 128 bits?

Comment: @DigitalGeeK Nop. Each address stores 1 byte. So a address range `002AF948 to 002AF94B` can store only 32 bits. To store 128 bits, you require 16 memory locations. So a address range `002AF948 to 002AF957` can store 128 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Four bytes are 32 bit since one byte is (normally) 8 bit.

In the past there have been some exotic exceptions to the 8 bit per byte rule but I don't think that they exist any longer.

Comment: What! I always taught that a byte = 8 bits.